# Mac OS not accessible

Tags: macos, mac, partition, unix, dual-boot

I was recently resizing a partition on my mac (10.13) and a partition came up named "recovery HD", I looked and saw that it only had 650mb. I tried to delete and couldn't along with the partitions that I was trying to resize.

I logged off and restarted to see if that would do anything. I have a Linux Distro duel booting on my Mac which I deleted trying to resize the partitions. I pressed the `option` key (`alt` in my case) so I could get the boot options because it will automatically boot Linux if I don't.

When the hard drives come up after pressing the `option` key, I could not find my Mac OS partition. I also erased my Linux files (not the partition because I couldn't as mentioned above) so I clicked on the Linux hard drive named EFI boot hoping to have the Mac OS somehow moved to the Linux partition, but as expected it comes up with a bash shell and doesn't load anything.

Luckily I can live boot Linux on my Mac and I still have the partition so I might try to install Linux on the partition, but I wanted my macOS back so I did the recovery mode `alt` + `R` which didn't work, just completely bypassed my keys and went to the hard drive with nothing on it. When I was on Linux boot Linux mode - Linux mint - I saw that the partition was a bunch of Fs: (I don't know how many Fs there were) FFFFFFFF-FFFFFFFFFFFF-FFFFFFF

Should I try to format the partition to APFS or Mac OS Extended (Journaled)? Or should I buy a download disk of Mac OS X 10.6 Snow Leopard and try to download it to the partition that should originally have Mac on it? Maybe I need to do both, or just format the FFFFFFFFF partition because maybe the boot options cant read the FFFFF format. But still, I have no idea if Mac OS got deleted or if there's anything to salvage. What is the best way to solve this problem, as I am inexperienced? I also don't care if any of the files on Mac OS are deleted. Whatever is the easiest is best. Thanks!

Comment: Firstly, welcome to Ask Different! :)  I hope you come to find this site has a lot to offer! In case you haven't already, it's worth taking the time to read the [tour](https://apple.stackexchange.com/tour). In the meantime your post reads as a wall of text and is very hard to follow. You may want to [edit](https://apple.stackexchange.com/posts/362011/edit) it to improve your chances of getting a good answer. **However, before you do, we already have a lot of similar questions about this topic, so you may want to do a [search](https://apple.stackexchange.com/search?q=FFFFFFFF).**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i finally figured it out. my situation without a recovery HD i had to either partition my internal HD in half for linux and macos or just by a external HD do i bought an external HD because i didn't want to mess with partitions and i also bought an installation usb of macOS el capitan. I formatted the external HD to macOS extended (journed) and installed os el capitan. i am now upgrading to high sierra because i have an old imac i cant get mojave. hopefully this helps! :)